# Data is not saved properly in MogoDB from Angular js through Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs

I am building an application with Angular.js,Node.js and MongoDB.

I am sending a set of data to MongoDB as below.

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url:'http://localhost:2000/postsharedata',  data:({event:$scope.event,date:$scope.eventdate,expenselist:$scope.expenses,expense:$scope.totalAmount,sharelist:$scope.sharelists,shareno:$scope.share()}),
}).success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

expenselist while sending to MongoDB is as follows:

```
[Object { text="a", done=true,$$hashKey="00I",$oldValue="5000",$value="5000"}]
```

But in mongoDb,data is like  `[ { "text" : "a", "done" : true }]`

Why $oldValue and $value are not getting stored?

Please Advice

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `$http` post service to submit your data to your server, angular converts your data and strips all properties that are prefixed with at least one `$` character. This is documented in the `toJson` function (`http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.toJson`).

If you want to submit your data regardless the leading `$` character you have to change the way how angular transforms your data before the submit happens. This can easily be done by using the `transformRequest` config parameter:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url:'http://localhost:2000/postsharedata',    
   data:(... your data ...),
   transformRequest: function(data){return data}
})
```

More information in the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service documentation.

Comment: Thanks.When I use the above solution,no data is getting stored in MongoDB

Comment: @User2404 see my edits. i have removed the noop function. With the approach you can see now you can do the mapping by yourself in the function.

Comment: Is there a need to do mapping while sending the request.In "data" itself,I have mapped the parameters

Comment: @User2404 it depends. I think you want always remove the $$hashKey from your data. So i would recommend write your own mapping function that you can reuse and put your data at the data parameter as you did before...